# Error initializing Java VM in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion

I am having an issue getting my Java to work on Mac OS X Lion.  I did the Java upgrade where it completly removed it.  Then I needed it again, and I did an install of 7v9.apps that didn't work.

I then did the Apple KB (knowledge-base) article of reverting it back to 6, but that didn't work.  I uninstalled it completely (many times now), and reinstall 7v9, but I can't get my apps to work nor can I get the java console to open.

Can anyone help? Here are my logs from the console:

```
10/31/12 3:01:44.681 PM [0x0-0x6ea6ea].com.apple.systempreferences: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/jcontrol: line 116: [: too many arguments

10/31/12 3:01:44.681 PM [0x0-0x6ea6ea].com.apple.systempreferences: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/jcontrol: line 120: [: -Xdock:icon=/Library/Internet: binary operator expected

10/31/12 3:01:44.723 PM [0x0-0x6ea6ea].com.apple.systempreferences: Error occurred during initialization of VM

10/31/12 3:01:44.723 PM [0x0-0x6ea6ea].com.apple.systempreferences: java.lang.NullPointerException

10/31/12 3:01:44.723 PM [0x0-0x6ea6ea].com.apple.systempreferences:     at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:542)

10/31/12 3:01:44.723 PM [0x0-0x6ea6ea].com.apple.systempreferences:     at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)

10/31/12 3:01:44.723 PM [0x0-0x6ea6ea].com.apple.systempreferences:     at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1115)
```

Comment: Wait, are those hex values memory addresses?  I thought the JVM *never* gave out memory addresses?

Comment: i dont know. thats the logs from the console..

Comment: What happens when you type 'java -version' from a terminal? (if Java 7U9 is installed, then you should get the following output "java version "1.7.0_09""

Comment: Check the file at `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/jcontrol` @ line 116.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> […]/jcontrol: line 116: [: too many arguments
> […]/jcontrol: line 120: [: -Xdock:icon=/Library/Internet: binary operator expected
> ```

It looks like there were syntax errors in that `jcontrol` file, which manifest themselves because some ancestor process set environment variables `_JCP_DOCK_NAME` and `_JCP_DOCK_ICON`. The output of `env | grep JCP` might be useful here. The `jcontrol` script can be fixed by adding quotes around these variables in the mentioned lines:

```sh
if [ -z "${_JCP_DOCK_NAME}" ]; then
    _JCP_DOCK_NAME=-Xdock:name="Java Control Panel"
fi

if [ -z "${_JCP_DOCK_ICON}" ]; then
    _JCP_DOCK_ICON=-Xdock:icon="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java7VM.icns"
fi
```

I'm far from sure whether this is the cause of the subsequent error messages, though.

> ```
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:542)
>     at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1115)
> ```

[`Hashtable.put`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/0e2200a8762c/src/share/classes/java/util/Hashtable.java) throws a null pointer exception if the `value` argument is `null`. It would have been interesting to know what key this is referring to, but the Java debugger probably won't be of much use when debugging this [native code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/0e2200a8762c/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c). Perhaps your best bet is to use a general application debugger like "gdb" in an attempt to figure out the key associated with the `null` value in that `put` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Library/Internet: binary operator expected
```

I had a similar error when trying to use [Oracle JDeveloper](https://www.oracle.com/technologies/developer-tools/jdeveloper/jdeveloper.html) on OS X.

I think the problem is the space in `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable. I simply made a symlink to the location of Oracle Java 1.7:

```
>ls -la /usr/local/oraclejava
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  64 20 Sep 13:33 /usr/local/oraclejava -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Re-launching the app after setting `$JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/local/oraclejava` fixed the problem.